# "network collection agent failed to start" when using Edge F12 network tab

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

It works fine in IE.

The hub collector service is set to manual and starts when going to Edge F12 network tab, but this error pops up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step is reload the F12 package:

```
Add-AppxPackage -register “C:\windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml” `
-DisableDevelopmentMode -Confirm:$false
```

for some reasons the problems is gone after I did a reset of Edge in the advanced options area of Edge in Apps & features.

How I did "Repair and reset the app":

Select the Start button > Settings > Apps > Apps & features. Select Edge, and then select Advanced options. On the page that opens with information about Edge, select Repair. when repairing the app doesn't fix the problem, select Reset.

Saved Tabs aside, browsing history etc. may be wiped but web credentials, favorites and read list are synchronized again after some minutes

an even further reset of Egde can be done like this:

1. Close all instances of Microsoft Edge
2. Open the following folder:
   `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
3. Delete (backup/copy) all folder inside. If you’re not able to delete the folders named AppData and AC, try stopping “Cryptographic Services” from the Services MMC first. `net stop cryptsvc`.  And then delete the two folders.
4. run with elevated powershell: `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, you should start a Admin commandline and execute this command:

```
sc config diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service start=demand
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It would be helpful if you explained what this command does and how it answers the OP's question.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This answer from the Microsoft forums helped me (or more simply, under services.msc started as Admin look for the service Microsoft (R) Diagnostics Hub Standard Collector Service and set the startup to "manual"):

If you disabled service diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service, it cause this issue.

Run this command in admin privilege, sc config diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service start= demand
If you wanna check this service status, `sc qc diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service`, the START_TYPE must not be set to disabled.

Comment: I mentioned that service in my Q....

Answer (score 0):

IE or Edge debugger: this is what occurs if you removed SYSTEM account rights on current user folders because this service is run by SYSTEM account.
In that case, give NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account full rights on this folder:

```
C:\Users\< user account >\AppData\LocalLow\Temp\Microsoft\F12
```